# Remove Jquery .css on unhover

Tags: jquery

How to remove .css("background","red"); from (A.yuimenubaritemlabel.sub) element after unhovering .yuimenuitemlabel element ?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".yuimenuitemlabel").mouseover(function(){
   $("A.yuimenubaritemlabel.sub").css("background","red");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to reset the css property on mouse leave.

```
$(".yuimenuitemlabel").mouseover(function(){
   $("A.yuimenubaritemlabel.sub").css("background","red");
}).mouseleave(function(){
     $("A.yuimenubaritemlabel.sub").css("background","");
});
```

Use hover function if you have do do many things you can use hover.

```
$(".yuimenuitemlabel").hover(function(){
   $("A.yuimenubaritemlabel.sub").css("background","red");
}, function(){
     $("A.yuimenubaritemlabel.sub").css("background","");
});
```

Use hover function assuming you just need to change the css. You can make two class one is sub and other is newsub.

```
$(".yuimenuitemlabel").hover(function(){
     $("A.yuimenubaritemlabel.sub").toggleClass("newsub");
});
```

Comment: Show us html or make a fiddle on jsfiddle.com

Answer (score 3):

It is a better practice to add/remove a class

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".yuimenuitemlabel").hover(function(){
        $("a.yuimenubaritemlabel.sub").toggleClass('hoverclass');
    });
});
```

And use a class with

```
.hoverclass{
   background-color:red;
}
```